# How to use sub views and sub view models

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

I am writing a WPF application with MvvmCross. I want to be able to have a content frame architecture in my views, so I can show different views while staying on the same page. Something like this:

```
<views:MvxWpfView
         x:Class="MyApp.WPF.Views.HomeView"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">

         <Grid>

             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>

             <Label Grid.Row=1 Content="This label will always be shown"/>

             <!-- I want to inject the associated View when I navigate to its ViewModel -->
             <views:MvxWpfView Grid.Row=2/>

         </Grid>

</views:MvxWpfView>
```

And then when I call something like

```
await NavigationService.Navigate<SubViewModel>();
```

It will load the associated `SubView` in the inner `MvxWpfView` and I will still see my label on top. I've worked with fragments in Android and I'm trying to get on the same path as that.

Comment: I don't think a call to Navigate is required. Once you inject the view in xaml, it will automatically load its viewmodel too.

Comment: That's a good idea. But how can I "swap" the main content `MvxWpfView` as needed?

Comment: Do you have multiple views that you wish to use in place of MvxWpfView?

Comment: Yes. When I use MvvmCross with Xamarin.Android, if I navigate to `SubViewModel` while using fragments, it will load the container view model as well, and anything else needed to display it. It seems that MvvmCross doesn't treat WPF the same way though.